# Spring cloud contract producer генерирует тест по контракту и в конце ставит null если добавлять body

Tags: spring-boot

Моя задача использовать Spring boot 1.5.6 и не выше

pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
     xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
     xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

<groupId>com.flamelab</groupId>
<artifactId>Contractserver</artifactId>
<version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>1.5.6.RELEASE</version>
</parent>

<properties>
    <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    <spring-boot.version>1.5.6.RELEASE</spring-boot.version>
    <spring-cloud-contract-verifier.version>2.1.1.RELEASE</spring-cloud-contract-verifier.version>
</properties>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-contract-verifier</artifactId>
        <version>${spring-cloud-contract-verifier.version}</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

</dependencies>

<dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-dependencies</artifactId>
            <version>${spring-boot.version}</version>
            <type>pom</type>
            <scope>import</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</dependencyManagement>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-contract-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <!--
                            <version>2.1.1.RELEASE</version>
            -->
            <extensions>true</extensions>
            <configuration>
                <baseClassForTests>com.flamelab.contract.ContractBaseTest</baseClassForTests>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.2</version>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

application.yml

```
spring:
  application:
    name: contract-server
server:
  port: 8081
```

Main класс

```
package com.flamelab;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;

@SpringBootApplication
public class ContractServerApplication {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(ContractServerApplication.class, args);
    }
}
```

Контроллер

```
package com.flamelab.controller;

import com.flamelab.service.MathActions;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.*;

@RestController
@RequestMapping("/math")
public class MathServerController {

    private MathActions mathActions;

    @Autowired
    public MathServerController(MathActions mathActions) {
        this.mathActions = mathActions;
    }

    @GetMapping("/multiply")
    @ResponseBody
    public Integer multiplyNumber(Integer number, Integer multiplier) {
        return mathActions.multiply(number, multiplier);
    }
}
```

Интерфейс для сервиса

```
package com.flamelab.service;

public interface MathActions {

    Integer multiply(Integer number, Integer multiplier);
}
```

Сервис (имплементирует интерфейс выше)

```
package com.flamelab.service;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

@Service
public class MathService implements MathActions {

    @Override
    public Integer multiply(Integer number, Integer multiplier) {
        return number * multiplier;
    }
}
```

Base test c MockMvc

```
package com.flamelab.contract;

import com.flamelab.controller.MathServerController;
import com.flamelab.service.MathService;
import io.restassured.module.mockmvc.RestAssuredMockMvc;
import org.junit.Before;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootTest;
import org.springframework.cloud.contract.verifier.messaging.boot.AutoConfigureMessageVerifier;
import org.springframework.test.annotation.DirtiesContext;
import org.springframework.test.context.ContextConfiguration;
import org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringRunner;
import org.springframework.test.context.web.AnnotationConfigWebContextLoader;

@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(loader = AnnotationConfigWebContextLoader.class)
@SpringBootTest(webEnvironment = SpringBootTest.WebEnvironment.MOCK)
@DirtiesContext
@AutoConfigureMessageVerifier
public abstract class ContractBaseTest {

    @Before
    public void setup() {
        RestAssuredMockMvc.standaloneSetup(new MathServerController(new MathService()));
    }

    public void makeMultiplying() {
    }
}
```

И контракт для контроллера на YAML

```
request:
    method: GET
    url: /math/multiply
    queryParameters:
        number : 2
        multiplier : 2

    headers:
        Content-Type: application/json

response:
    status: 200
    headers:
        Content-Type: application/json;charset=UTF-8
    body: 4
```

Итак, если в контракте закомментировать body: 4 (сделать #body: 4) и собрать через mvn clean install - тогда тест проходит нормально и в папке target\generated-test-sources\contracts\com\flamelab\contract генерируется тест

```
package com.flamelab.contract;

import com.flamelab.contract.ContractBaseTest;
import com.jayway.jsonpath.DocumentContext;
import com.jayway.jsonpath.JsonPath;
import io.restassured.module.mockmvc.specification.MockMvcRequestSpecification;
import io.restassured.response.ResponseOptions;
import java.io.StringReader;
import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilder;
import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilderFactory;
import org.junit.Test;
import org.w3c.dom.Document;
import org.xml.sax.InputSource;

import static com.toomuchcoding.jsonassert.JsonAssertion.assertThatJson;
import static io.restassured.module.mockmvc.RestAssuredMockMvc.*;
import static org.springframework.cloud.contract.verifier.assertion.SpringCloudContractAssertions.assertThat;
import static org.springframework.cloud.contract.verifier.util.ContractVerifierUtil.*;

public class MathTest extends ContractBaseTest {

    @Test
    public void validate_mathControllerContract() throws Exception {
        // given:
            MockMvcRequestSpecification request = given()
                    .header("Content-Type", "application/json");

        // when:
            ResponseOptions response = given().spec(request)
                    .queryParam("number","2")
                    .queryParam("multiplier","2")
                    .get("/math/multiply");

        // then:
            assertThat(response.statusCode()).isEqualTo(200);
            assertThat(response.header("Content-Type")).isEqualTo("application/json;charset=UTF-8");
    }

}
```

Когда же body: 4 открыт - тогда появляется тот же самый тест MathTest, но отличае в нём в том, что в самом конце появляется дополнительный null

```
// and:
            DocumentContext parsedJson = JsonPath.parse(response.getBody().asString());
            String responseBody = response.getBody().asString();
            null; - от этого надо избавится, чтобы оно генернировало тест с проверкой на то, что присылается в body 4, как указано в контракте
    }
```

ну и билд падает с естественной ошибкой MathTest.java:[40,25] not a statement

Помогите пожалуйста решить проблему с null вместо проверки на body: 4.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Сталкивался с аналогичной проблемой.

Все дело в

```
headers:
        Content-Type: application/json;charset=UTF-8
body: 4
```

Spring cloud contract не может сгенерировать правильный assert из-за того, что content-type - json, но при этом body - обычный текст. Поменяйте header ответа на "text/plain", либо измените ваш код таким образом, чтобы возвращался примерно такой json :

```
{ "result": 4 }
```

Comment: Спасибо, это именно то, что нужно было. В контроллере поменял метод на такую строку 
    @GetMapping(value = "/multiply", produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
    @ResponseBody
    public Map<String, Integer> multiplyNumber(Integer number, Integer multiplier) {
        Integer resultOfMultiplying = mathActions.multiply(number, multiplier);
        Map<String, Integer> result = new HashMap<>();
        result.put("result", resultOfMultiplying);
        return result;
    }     и в контракте указал body: {
        "result": 4
    }